# Onto and one to one maps

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need help with the following problem:

> Construct an example of maps $f\colon S \to T$ and $g\colon T\to S$ in which $f$ is one-to-one and $g$ is onto, but the composite $g\circ f$ is neither one-to-one nor onto.

I have tried many different examples but I keep running into the problem that $g\circ f$ is onto.

Comment: I suggest you stop making $g$ onto as well, and more generally I would advise against having its image intersect all preimages of points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $S=T=\mathbb Z$. Define $f,g\colon\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ as follows: for $n\in\mathbb Z$,
\begin{equation}
f(n)=2n,\qquad g(n)=
\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if $n$ is even},\\
(n+1)/2, &\text{if $n$ is odd}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Then we can see that $f$ and $g$ satisfy the condition.